# Vue not printing variable value using Algolia following Laracasts Search as a Service: Javascript Baby Steps

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I get to 5:35 in the video but when I test it {{ user.make }} gets printed out without the value of the variable replacing {{ user.make }}. It should be "600AJ" but its {{ user.make }} printed on the screen. I am trying to do this in a laravel app, all my code is in the resources/layouts/app.blade.php page.  When I try to load say welcome.blade.php in the browser {{ user.make }} gets printed instead of "600AJ". Any thoughts?

For those that are not familiar with the tutorial video here is the code:

```
<div class="results">

<article v-repeat="user: users">
    <h2>@{{ user.make }}</h2>
    <h2>@{{ user.model }}</h2>
</article>
</div>

<script>

new Vue({
    el: 'body',

    data: { users: [] },

    ready: function() {
        this.client = algoliasearch('key1','key2');
        this.index = this.client.initIndex('test_contacts');



        index.search('600aj', function(error, results) {
                this.users = results.hits;
            }.bind(this));
        }

});
```

Comment: Looking at your code, and It's 0.x VueJS version syntax.What version you included in your development ?
Try to change `v-repeat="user: users"` to `v-for="user in users"`

Comment: I'm pulling in the most recent CDN's for Algolia and Vue, I made the change you suggested but it still doesnt print out the value of the variable, it just prints out {{ user.make }}  I also get an error: [Vue warn]: Do not mount Vue to <html> or <body> - mount to normal elements instead???

Comment: Then wrap your app into the `div#app` and then into Vue instance set `el: '#app'` instead of `el: 'body'`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me but I cant get it to work, maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "wrap your app into the div#app".  Should my div class=results be switched to div id=app?  Or should div id=app wrap the div and article I have above?  I've tried both with no success.  Let me know what I should do, thanks!

Comment: I mean like this https://jsbin.com/caverobequ/edit?html,js,console,output, oh and if you are on VueJS 2, you should use mounted keyword instead of ready.

Comment: So at the end try to go with this https://jsbin.com/yifevexawu/edit?html,js,output
Sorry but I don't have experience with Algolia Search, so in fact I can't help you on that point.